# Application of natural boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I am trying to apply a time dependent load in AceFEM, for which i have used adaptive time method for analysis, also i need it to be applied at the nodal points from 1 to 15. So i have used natural boundary condition and gave the command but have encountered error that my "Boundary condition is not of prescribed form". Please guide me

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
P = 1000000; 
SMTAddDomain["Ω","ML:SEPET1DFLET1DHooke", {"E *" -> 1000, "ν *" -> 0.3}];
SMTAddMesh[ToElementMesh[
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 > 0.05, {x, y}],
 {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},"MeshOrder" -> 1], "Ω"
];
Clear[λ];
λ[t_] := P (1 - t/0.008);
Plot[λ[t], {t, 0, 0.008}]
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 1 -> λ[t]];
SMTAnalysis[];

SMTNextStep["Δt" -> 0.008, "λ[t]" -> λ];
While[
  While[
    step=SMTConvergence[10^-8,15, {"Adaptive Time", 8, .00001, 0.01, 10}], 
    SMTNewtonIteration[];
];
If[
  step[[4]] === "MinBound",
  SMTStatusReport["Analyze"]; 
  SMTStepBack[];
];
step[[3]],
If[
  step[[1]],
  SMTStepBack[];
];
SMTNextStep["Δt" -> step[[2]],"λ[t]" -> λ]];

Show[
  SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx","Contour" ->True]
 ]
```

Comment: Do you get any specific errors?

Comment: I am getting this error
Error in natural boundary condition.
 Description : Bondary condition is not of the prescribed form.
 Problematic natural boundary condition:
 {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 1 -> 1000000*(1 - 125.*t)}
Node:1
Value:\{1.*10^6 (1. -125. t)}
Version: 6.816 Windows (10 May 17) (MMA 11
See also: Input Data  AceFEM Troubleshooting  Continue
 for this particular code
    \[Lambda][t_] := P (1 - t/0.008);
    Plot[\[Lambda][t], {t, 0, 0.008}]
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
   15}, 1 -> \[Lambda][t]];

Comment: @SwapnilAgarwal In the "Cyclic tension test" example from the manual only essential boundary conditions are specified, while the error message you posted in the comment mentions natural boundary conditions (`SMTAddNaturalBoundary`). Can you please edit your question to include all the code you have used and a clearly explain your goals.

Comment: @Pinti mam, I have made the changes to question and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, but lets first address the source of error message about "Boundary condition is not of prescribed form".

Bellow I have copied the first section of your original code, up until `SMTAnalysis` command. After this we can already check if our data structures have been input correctly. (All built-in symbols/functions start with capital letter, your symbols defined in notebook should start with lowercase letter, so they can be easily distinguished. Keep in mind this good practice.)

```
<< AceFEM`; 

(* Note: This code section has intentional errors! *)
SMTInputData[];
P = 1000000; 
SMTAddDomain["Ω","ML:SEPET1DFLET1DHooke", {"E *" -> 1000, "ν *" -> 0.3}];
SMTAddMesh[ToElementMesh[
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 > 0.05, {x, y}],
 {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},"MeshOrder" -> 1], "Ω"
];
Clear[λ];
λ[t_] := P (1 - t/0.008);
Plot[λ[t], {t, 0, 0.008}]
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 1 -> λ[t]];
SMTAnalysis[];
```

When you evaluate this code you get the error message saying "Error in natural boundary condition". Reason for this is that syntax `SMTAddNaturalBoundary[..., 1 -> λ[t]];` is wrong. See the quote from documentation:

[image: documentation screenshot]

Current value of boundary conditions (*Bt*) is calculated from its value in previous time/load step (*Bp*): *Bt=Bp+Δλ dB*. Multiplier increment *Δλ* and reference BC intensity *dB* can have arbitrary values, but value of their product should be meaningful. Typically *dB* is set to 1 and multiplier *λ* goes from 0 to its final value. Multiplier can be also a function of time *λ[t]* and then time *t* goes from 0 to final time.

So, changing the definition of natural BC removes the error message, but there is another problem.

```
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 1 -> 1];
```

You apply the force (natural BC) to nodes with specific node numbers from 1-15, but how can you be sure upfront what are the node numbers on your mesh in some area of interest. See the picture bellow, where one node on the inner edge doesn't get the applied force, but it probably should.

[image: wrong mesh]

It is much better to find nodes of interest with appropriate "node selector", some function of their initial position. This is the whole block of code for correct definition of input phase. For NBC all nodes on the circle with the specified radius are chosen.

```
(* This definition of hole size is clearer. *)
holeRadius = 0.25;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["Ω","ML:SEPET1DFLET1DHooke", {"E *" -> 1000, "ν *" -> 0.3}];
SMTAddMesh[
  ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 > holeRadius^2, {x, y}], {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1],
  "Ω"];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[Line[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}], 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0];
SMTAddNaturalBoundary[("X"^2 + "Y"^2 == holeRadius^2) &, 1 -> 1];
SMTAnalysis[];

SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions"->True,PlotRange->0.5,ImageSize->200]
```

[image: correct mesh]

Time always starts from 0 and I think BC multiplier should also start from 0, but it can change as arbitrary function of time.

```
Clear[λ];
maxLoad = 1000000;
maxTime = 0.008;
λ[t_] := maxLoad*(t/maxTime)
(*Plot[λ[t],{t,0,0.008}]*)
```

These are key parameters for `SMTConvergence` that guide time stepping. Analysis will finish with somewhere between 10 and 100 steps. The first step will be smaller that maximum allowed step.

```
Δt0 = maxTime/20;
ΔtMax = maxTime/10;
ΔtMin = maxTime/100;
```

I am going to write explanation for analysis loop with inline comments, because it will be more readable. Analysis loop has two `While` loops, the outer controls time/load stepping and the inner controls number of (Newton-Rhapson) iterations for each step.

```
(* Increase values of BC for the first step. 
 Size of time step is prescribed, and the load multiplier changes according to function λ. *)
SMTNextStep["Δt" -> Δt0,"λ[t]" -> λ];

While[
  (* Do iterations until SMTConvergence returns something else than explicit True. 
  In case of "Adaptive Time" this is a list of 4 elements that guide     further behaviour of analysis loop.
   Return value of SMTConvergence is assigned to symbol step. *)
  While[
   step = 
    SMTConvergence[10^-8,15, {"Adaptive Time",8, ΔtMin, ΔtMax, maxTime}], 
   SMTNewtonIteration[];
   ];
  If[
    Not[step[[1]]],
    (* All the code for collecting results goes here. 
    Code is evaluated only if no step back is needed. *)
    SMTShowMesh[
     "DeformedMesh"->False,"BoundaryConditions"->True,"Field"->"Sxx", "Contour" -> {-10^6, 10^6, 7},
    "Show" -> "Window" | {"Animation", "MyTestName", ImageSize -> 400}]
  ];
  If[
   step[[4]] === "MinBound",
   SMTStatusReport["Analyze"];
   SMTStepBack[];
   ];
  (* step[[3]] is test for outer While. This is the result of the last evaluation of SMTConvergence. 
  If it is True analysis should make another step (forward or backward). 
  It is False only if the final time has been reached or analysis has diverged. *)
  step[[3]],
  If[
   step[[1]],
   SMTStepBack[];
   ];
  (* If analysis has converged in the last step and has not yet reached the final value of time, 
  another step should be made. 
  Step size is prescribed by SMTConvergence and saved in step[[2]]. *)
  SMTNextStep["Δt" -> step[[2]],"λ[t]" -> λ]
  ];

SMTShowMesh["BoundaryConditions"->True,"Contour" -> True,"Field" -> "Sxx", "Mesh" -> Gray, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: result]

Comment: when I was going through the manual I did understand why the part where Boundary condition was showing an error that but after running the code.So i had change it as you mentioned but the response is same as static load.

Comment: @SwapnilAgarwal The example you gave in you question is quasi-static. Inertial effects are neglected and in absence of other time dependent phenomena the response is independent of time. You can find example of implicit dynamic analysis in AceFEM documentation in "2D snooker simulation" example. If you are interested in dynamic analysis you should ask another question with very clear explanation of your goals.

Comment: Why is there no change in stresses when i keep 
      
   ` λ[t_] := maxLoad*(1-(t/maxTime))`
Is there any possible way to load this kind of condition.
Also is there any mistake in the way i am using this animation command.
  ` SMTMakeAnimation["blast", "gif","AnimationRepitions"->Infinity ]`
I am getting the error of no frames have been stored under this keyword

Comment: @SwapnilAgarwal There is no stress, because with your definition of `λ[t_]` the final value of BC multiplier is zero (`λ[maxTime]==0`), so applied forces are zero.   For making animation you have to first save its frames during the analysis. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thank You

Comment: @SwapnilAgarwal I'm glad to help. Please see also ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Done, still can't vote yet.